# Commonjs : during the build, How to change the extension of file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, commonjs

I am able to transpile scss file to css file but the only importing is not working during the build. since *.js its importing a .scss file. I tried replacing .scss with .css during the build.

**js still has references to scss files which do not exist in the dist folder as all scss there is distributes as normal css**

**error :**

```
ERROR in ./src/Checkbox/Checkbox.js                               
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Checkbox.css' in '/src/Checkbox'
         @ ./src/Checkbox/Checkbox.js 36:0-22
         @ ./src/index.js**
```

**src/checkbox.js**

```
'use strict';
import {Checkbox} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Style
import './Checkbox.scss';
 react code...
```

**dist/checkbox.js** transpiled JS file (looks like )

```
var _propTypes2 = _interopRequireDefault(_propTypes);

require('./Checkbox.scss');

**I am expecting require('./Checkbox.css');**

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }                                                
and so on ...
```

*.js its importing a .scss file. I tried replacing .scss with .css during the build

**my webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractLESS_checkbox = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'component/Checkbox.css',
  allChunks: true
});
const config = {
  entry : {
    index:'./src/index.js'
  },
  output : {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    pathinfo: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      //enforce: 'pre',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      enforce: 'pre',
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
         ['css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader']})

    ]
  },
plugins: [
    extractLESS_checkbox
  ],
externals: {
    'react/addons': true,
    'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
    'react/lib/ReactContext': true
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

**my package.json**

```
"name": "name",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "Elements",
"author": "dg",
 "license": "ISC",
  "jsnext:main": "dist/es/index.js",
  "main": "dist/commonjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/es/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:commonjs && npm run build:es",
so on ....
  } 
  "dependencies" : { ...} 
  "devDependencies" : {... }
```

Am I doing something wrong, Please suggest me

Comment: Why don't you try the recommended config from https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader ?
You just need style-loader, css-loader, sass-loader to make things work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, As you suggested, modified my webpack-config.js file but still I am running into the same issue. Plz have a look src/checkbox.js and transpiled dist/checkbox.js file. Please suggest how can I get rid of this issue.

Comment: js still has references to scss files which do not exist in the dist folder as all scss there is distributes as normal css

Answer (score 0):

## Use Extract text plugin

```
use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
            },
        }, {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true
            },
        }, {
            loader: 'import-glob-loader',
        },
    ]
})
```

Should look something like this

Comment: replace `rules: [{` width `loaders: [{`. also what version of webpack are you using. the syntax is a bit different in 3

Comment: webpack version ^3.3.0" ..  no luck :(